# Is there a Non-Sqlalchemy way to deal with many-to-many relationships in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-design, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I've searched for quite a long time on the web for a method that deals with many-to-many relationships in python sqlite3, but all seems to lead to Sqlalchemy. I'm not against using sqlalchemy at all(although I do find it an overkill from time to time and it does introduce some unnecessary logic in many cases), I was wondering if there is a 'golden class/function' that provides basic CRUD interface directly without bothering Sqlalchemy? Any references (online or paper-based) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The question is not if you can deal with many-to-many in python but in SQL. Sqlalchemy is only a library built on top of the SQL language and the sqlite API (amongst others). Many-to-many relationship is implemented using a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Or do you mean you are looking for an Object-Relational Mapper lighter than Sqlalchemy that supports many-to-many?

Comment: Exactly Cilyan! That's exactly what I'm looking for, a lighter weighted ORM! I love this forum, full of true genius. You guys can phrase a technical question so elegantly!

Comment: Oh, by the way, please don't suggest jango, that's no much lighter than sqlalchemy, in my opinion.:)

Comment: I think you're going to find it hard to find something that is LIGHTER than SQLAlchemy and yet simultaneously provides MORE FEATURES than SQLAlchemy. In any case, this question basically asks for a recommendation for a tool, which is specifically one of the types of questions that StackOverflow is not built to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at other ORMs than SqlAlchemy, you can compare the ORMs presented here: [What are some good Python ORM solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions)

I personnaly tried [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/) that supports Many-to-Many almost transparently but you have to write SQL to create the table (IIRC).

I also tried autumn which is dead but a fork exists: [AutORM](https://github.com/umidev/autorm). It is very lightweight but doesn't support many-to-many. You probably can work that around by declaring your junction table explicitly and it is targeted to sqlite (see peewee).

I tested dejavu (dead) and [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) which also doesn't have many-to-many transparently but explains [how to do it in its docs](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/docs/peewee/models.rst#implementing-many-to-many) (you can apply the same to AutORM).

*For my own case I used SqlAlchemy finally because the machinery necessary for ORMs is anyway so big that I preferred getting more functions for the price and at that time Python 3 support was not that common (my two cents :-) ).*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve many-to-many relations in basic SQL you can do this manualy using third table for storing those relations.

```
CREATE TABLE users {
    int user_id,
    varchar user_name
};

CREATE TABLE categories {
    int category_id,
    varchar category_name
};

CREATE TABLE category_permission {
    int user_id,
    int category_id
};  -- for storing relations
```

These three tables represents two models (`user`, `category`) and one many-to-many relation (`category_permission`)

You have to query them manualy and also manualy maintain stored relations. Based on SQL engine you are using you should consider using

- unique index in table category_permission on all two collumns
- foreing keys to maintain relations when deleting something.

You can then select this way:

```
-- to list all users and their category count
SELECT U.user_name, count(CP.category_id) as 'permitted'
FROM users U 
LEFT JOIN category_permission PM
    ON PM.user_id = U.user_id
ORDER BY permitted DESC;  


 -- to list all categories for __desired_user__
SELECT C.* FROM categories C
JOIN category_permission CM
    ON CM.category_id = C.category_id
WHERE CM.user_id = __desired_user_id__;
```

For further reference search for SQL solution instead of Python (which will always lead you to some framework). Many-to-many relationship is a common problem in relation databases.

- [Mysql database design in a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103461/mysql-database-design-in-a-many-to-many-relationship)
- [MySQL many-to-many relationship with FOREIGN KEYS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459762/mysql-many-to-many-relationship-with-foreign-keys)
- ... and so on ...

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for this answer, but I was actually looking for a canonical way to build a parent class that provide a very light-weight Object-relational mapper, and it should receive arbitary **kw arguments and decides intelligently manipulate the underlying many-to-many CRUD operations on the tables. I'm very surprised that I will have to resort Mysql examples. Why is there no such examples on sqlite, which is more common with Python programming?

Comment: Probably you can do this parent class with `dataset` for dealing with SQL (https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)